# How do you set a users group?

Tags: users, php

I am using the `UserModel` to create a user, and then injecting that into the User API service as is instructed in the documentation. The only thing I am not seeing is how to set the group.

I looked in the Model class and there is no method for setting the group and it's not part of the `defineAttributes()` method.

In the documentation there is no method to set group, just read only the groups: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/usermodel#getGroups

Nothing here about it: https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService

Here is what I am doing to save user.

```php
$user = new UserModel;

$user->username = 'username';
$user->email = 'yourmom@email.com';
// $user->groupID = "group";
$user->firstName = 'first name';
$user->lastName = 'last name';
$user->getContent()->setAttributes([ 'usersAddress' => 'Your face' ]);

craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not documented, but `UserGroupsService` has a method `assignUserToGroups($userId, int|array $groupIds)`. You'll have to save your user first, but once you have a user id, I believe you can just use that with something like this:

```php
// Original code
$user = new UserModel;

$user->username = 'username';
$user->email = 'user@email.com';
$user->firstName = 'first name';
$user->lastName = 'last name';
$user->getContent()->setAttributes([ 'usersAddress' => 'Your face' ]);

craft()->users->saveUser($user);

// Add to single group
craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, $groupId);

// OR, add to multiple groups
craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, [$groupIdOne, $groupIdTwo]);
```

Comment: I'll try this. If anyone else know how to do it without saving first that's ideal. But as always Matt Stauffer you handsome intelligent bastard you.

Comment: HA! How YOU doin...

Comment: All worked great! Hope they document that somewhere.